# Getting number of values entered on console

Tags: java, collections

In the below code I have taken three sets of values (`i<3`) in the first for loop. I am able to compute the same data using different integers, e.g. `i<5`, `i<6`. Please suggest a way where I can get the number of values that are being entered on the console and then use them as `<(number of values entered/2)`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("please enter 3 birth - death pairs");
  List<Dinosaur> dinoList = new ArrayList<Dinosaur>();
  // int dinoStrength=s.nextInt();


  for (int i = 0; i <3; i++) 
  {
    int num1 = s.nextInt();
    int num2 = s.nextInt();
    Dinosaur d = new Dinosaur(num1, num2);
    dinoList.add(d);

  }
  //System.out.println(dinoList);

  Collections.sort(dinoList);

  //System.out.println(dinoList);
  int maxCount = 0;
  List<String> ls=new ArrayList<String>();

  for (Dinosaur dino : dinoList) 
  {
    // System.out.println("start date" + dino.getStartDate());
    // System.out.println("end date"+ dino.getEndDate());
    int count = 0;
    for (Dinosaur dino2 : dinoList) {

      if (dino2.getStartDate() <= dino.getEndDate()
          && dino2.getEndDate() >= dino.getStartDate())
        count++;

    }
    //System.out.println(count);

    if (maxCount < count) {
      maxCount = count;
      ls.clear();
      ls.add(dino.getStartDate()+"-"+dino.getEndDate());
    }

    else if(maxCount==count)

    {
      ls.add(dino.getStartDate()+"-"+dino.getEndDate());
    }
  }
  //System.out.println(maxCount);

  //System.out.println(ls);

  System.out.println("Max no of Dinos alive at the same time :"+maxCount);
}
```

Comment: Replace `for(int i=0;i <3;i++)` with `while(s.hasNextInt())`

Comment: @Peter it is not helping, i just keep entering values without any result

Comment: You won't get a result until you end the input or the stream of numbers.  How would you like to do this? (In this case you can write anything which is not a number, like `end`)

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("please enter 3 birth - death pairs");
List<Dinosaur> dinoList = new ArrayList<Dinosaur>();
// int dinoStrength=s.nextInt();


while(s.hasNextInt())
{

int num1 = s.nextInt();
int num2 = s.nextInt();
if(num2 ==num1)//Your condition(Here I assume date of birth should not be equal to death date.)
break;
Dinosaur d = new Dinosaur(num1, num2);
dinoList.add(d);

}
```

You can try something like this .